# Add Elements of a List together while Maintaining the Larger List

Tags: python, list, element

I have a list in the following format:

```
[(('ABC','DEF'),2), (('GHI','JKL'), 4) ...]
```

I would like to break down to:

```
[('ABC','DEF', 2), ('GHI','JKL', 4) ...]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a simple *list comprehension*:

```
L = [(('ABC', 'DEF'), 2), (('GHI', 'JKL'), 4)]

new_list = [e[0] + (e[1],) for e in L]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> print new_list
[('ABC', 'DEF', 2), ('GHI', 'JKL', 4)]
```

**Note:** `e[0]` is a tuple and `e[1]` is an integer. The part `(e[1],)` will create a tuple with one element.

Comment: If you know that `e` will have exactly two elements, you could something like: `[t + (n,) for t, n in L]` (but with meaningful variable names).